# How to obtain the HTTP request body (string) from an instance of javax.ws.rs.client.Entity?

Tags: java, json, entity

I've an instance of javax.ws.rs.client.Entity. Here is the string representation of the instance:

```
Entity{entity=Entity{entity=class Pet {
id: 10
category: null
name: test something
photoUrls: []     
tags: null
status: null
}, variant=Variant[mediaType=application/json, language=null, encoding=null], annotations=[]}, variant=Variant[mediaType=application/json, language=null, encoding=null], annotations=[]}
```

For this example, it's a Pet object with JSON as the content type.

How can I obtain the HTTP request body string from the `entity` instance before using Invocation.Builder to send out the HTTP request?

(If the payload is HTTP form parameters and the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I also need to obtain the HTTP request body string representing the form parameters)

Comment: Would be nice to describe how would you use it, why do you need it

Comment: For HTTP signature authentication, I need the request body to compute the `digest`

Comment: Are you going to modify the request before sending using such an interceptor?

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/joyent/java-http-signature/blob/master/jaxrs-client/src/main/java/com/joyent/http/signature/jaxrs/client/SignedRequestClientRequestFilter.java Does it make sense?

Comment: I only need to read the HTTP request body (as a string). No modification to the body.

Comment: Thanks for the link but that does not seem to use javax.ws.rs.client.Entity